# App compatible with IOS 6 and its previous versions

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have developed an application in iOS 5 but now I want to convert same app in iOS 6 and also works on previous versions. Can anyone explain in detail how I can achieved this functionality?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Can anyone explain in detail" vs. "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or **extended discussion**..." Explaining in detail is the task of the documentation, not of SO.

Comment: My question is that How I can develop a application in iOS 6 & compatible with its previous versions?? For example: in iOS 6 , facebook & twitter are implemented through SLRequest & account framework. Now I want to run this iOS 6 app on iOS 5. Now How these features (facebook & twitter) will be supported in iOS 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IOS 5 application works fine on IOS 6.
Only It is displayed at center because in IOS 6 height is increased.

If you want to create new version for IOS 6 then create create view separately as shown below.

```
float height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

if(height==568)
{
      //give frames according to IOS 6    
}
else
{
      //give frames according to IOS 5    
}
```

Comment: @Durgaprasad- Thank you for your code. Its working perfectly in my app.